# Qt MainWindow Exits after QMessageBox is closed

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to Make a small tool which has to be hidden on startup so im doing :

```
w.showMinimized();
w.hide();
```

on main.cpp which calls my MainWindow in a hidden mode , but the problem is that when i call FinishSession() which is a function on the class ProductDlg which is called from MainWindow of Course , it exists whenever i click "Yes OR No" from the QMessageBox you see bellow

```
void ProductsDlg::FinishSession()
{
    if(Session)
    {
        if(this->isActiveWindow())
        {
            this->hide();
        }

        QMessageBox::StandardButton _finishSession = QMessageBox::question(this , "Question" , "Do you wanna Finish the Session ?" , QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No); // THIS MESSAGEBOX - IT EXISTS AFTER THIS

        if(_finishSession == QMessageBox::Yes)
        {
            Session = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "No Session is Running";
    }
}
```

This is from MainWindow.cpp where i call ProductsDlg :

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType , void *message , long *result)
{
    Q_UNUSED(eventType);
    Q_UNUSED(result);

    MSG * msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if(msg->message == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        if(msg->wParam == 0)
        {
            if(!pd->isVisible())
            {
                QRect rect = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
                pd->show();
                pd->setFocus();
                pd->activateWindow();
                pd->move(rect.width() - pd->width() , rect.height());
                QPropertyAnimation *ani = new QPropertyAnimation(pd , "pos");
                ani->setDuration(700);
                ani->setStartValue(pd->pos());
                ani->setEndValue(QPoint(rect.width() - pd->width() , rect.height() - pd->height()));
                ani->start();
            }
            else if(!pd->isActiveWindow())
            {
                pd->activateWindow();
            }
            else if(pd->isActiveWindow())
            {
                pd->hide();
            }
        }

        else if(msg->wParam == 1)
        {
            pd->FinishSession();
        }

        else if(msg->wParam == 2)
        {
            if(pd->isActiveWindow())
            {
                pd->hide();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

'pd' is defined globally and initialized on the MainWindow Constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here : 
[Qt 5.1 - QMessageBox Bug? Program Exits(0) if QMessageBox is called while QDialog is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370656/qt-5-1-qmessagebox-bug-program-exits0-if-qmessagebox-is-called-while-qdialo?rq=1)

I added `qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);` to main.cpp an the problem is solved !